# WPF SelectionChange Event for ComboBox with Binding from database crashes the Program

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, combobox

I've got a big issue trying to modify the ItemSource for a ComboBox. When I try to debug the app by putting a breakpoint on MessageBox.Show(...) in the Sub cboTest_SelectionChanged (see below), I get this error:

```
An Unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occured in Data.exe

Additional Information: 
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem'
```

How can I fix this?

Here's what I do. I create an ACCESS 2007 Database named SNIGDoFFE.accdb, my solution is named **Data**, I added the Database through the **Add New Source Configuration wizard** and I drag and drop the Field **"Libelle"** from the Table **Ethnie** to the the ComboBox, so it modifies my files like this:

In MainWindow.xaml.vb

```
Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    Dim SNIGDoFFEDataSet As Data.SNIGDoFFEDataSet = CType(Me.FindResource("SNIGDoFFEDataSet"), Data.SNIGDoFFEDataSet)
    'Load data into the table Ethnie. You can modify this code as needed.
    Dim SNIGDoFFEDataSetEthnieTableAdapter As Data.SNIGDoFFEDataSetTableAdapters.EthnieTableAdapter = New Data.SNIGDoFFEDataSetTableAdapter.EthnieTableAdapter()
    SNIGDoFFEDataSetEthnieTableAdapter.Fill(SNIGDoFFEDataSet.Ethnie)
    Dim EthnieViewSource As System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource = CType(Me.FindResource("EthnieViewSource"), System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)
    'EthnieViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst
    'I comment this line to leave the combobox empty

End Sub
```

The code for cboTest_SelectionChanged is:

```
Private Sub cboTesT_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles cboTesT.SelectionChanged
    MessageBox.Show(CType(cboTesT.SelectedItem, ComboBoxItem).Content)
End Sub
```

In XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboTest" width="120" Margin"184,10,183,134" SelectionChanged="cboTest_SelectionChanged" DisplayMemberPath="Libelle" ItemSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EthnieViewSource}}" />
```

In my Resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <local:SNIGDoFFEDataSet x:Key"SNIGDoFFEDataSet" />
   <CollectionViewSource x:Key="EthnieViewSource" Source="{Binding Ethnie, Source={StaticResources SNIGDoFFEDataSet}}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

**The Solution is built correctly, the main Window loaded correctly, but when I select an item in the combobox, the program crashes. I try to remove all binding and create Item with  and everything work, but by binding the source from my database, it crashes again.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Mark, to be so long
and again I'm sorry a lot

on msdn forum, they told me that as the binding source is a Table in a database I must use DataRowView instead of ComboBoxItem,

```
Dim drv As System.Data.DataRowView = CType(cboTest.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
MessageBox.show(drv("Libelle").ToString())
```

Don't hesitate to help me another time, please.

Comment: No need to apologise. My answer said the same thing, just with a bit more information. I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

The program crashes because you allow the exception to propagate out of your code. To stop the program from crashing, place everything in your SelectedChange event handler in a try catch block.
This should become a standard for all 'windows entry points' into your code. Whether it is an event or a command, if you didn't call it from your code, use a try catch block to stop exceptions from propagating out of your code.

Regarding the error, you are binding data to your ComboBox. When you interrogate the SelectedItem, it will be of the type of the data (in your case, of type System.Data.DataRowView), not a ComboBoxItem.

If you need the containing ComboBoxItem of the selected item, use the [ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)() to find it, for example

```
Private Sub cboTesT_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles cboTesT.SelectionChanged
    Try
        Dim combo As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
        Dim item As ComboBoxItem = combo.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(combo.SelectedItem)
        MessageBox.Show(item.Content)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Log or display exception.
    End Try
End Sub
```

If you are just after the data, CType the SelectedItem to your datatype (System.Data.DataRowView) and work with it directly.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Mark, Sorry to take so long to answer. When I try your proposition, it always show the error message I show in Catch Block. but the program doesn't crash anymore

Comment: sure, ComboBoxItem for ComboBoxSource that's not a database. And SelectedItem for source that's database. I got It. Thanks

Comment: Your code will throw an error as you are incorrectly casting the SelectedItem. The TryCatch block fixed the application freeze but not the underlying problem. In your answer and my answer both, the underlying problem is fixed by correctly casting the SelectedItem. *This comment belongs before the comment above*.

Comment: Hi Woresa, I re-submitted the comment to remove spelling errors for future viewers. The first sentence will now make sense. Don't worry about responding to this comment. I will delete it tomorrow.